# Adding function to interface decorator pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

**Hello**,

I'm trying to wrap my head around the decorator pattern, and I'm not sure about something :

Is considered a bad practice or a misuse of the pattern to add a function to the interface when I want to add a new functionality ?

For example if I have a **Car** interface, and I want to make it amphibious with a decoration, is it allowed to add a `getAquaticSpeed()` function to the interface only for the purpose of adding this functionality ?

Thanks in advance !

Code example :

```java
interface Car{
   public float getSpeed();
}

public class CarFrame implements Car{
    public float getSpeed(){return 0;}
}

public abstract CarDecorator implements Car{
    private Car delegate;

    public CarDecorator(Car delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate
    }

    public float getSpeed(){return delegate.getSpeed();}
}
```

If i want to add an aquatic speed, colors etc. to my Car, is it allowed to add new function to my main interface ?

Like so :

```java
interface Car{
   public float getSpeed();
   public float getAquaticSpeed();
   public String getColor();
}
```

Comment: You can, of course, extend the Car interface and add the additional methods to that.

Comment: related: [Decorator Pattern with added functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75065105/decorator-pattern-with-added-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can add to the API of a Decorator, making it a superset of the interface in the object that it wraps. The first sentence in the Decorator chapter of the GoF book is,

> Intent
> Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically.

The UML structure on page 177 of the book shows concrete decorators with `addedState` as well as `AddedBehavior()` so attaching a responsibility by adding a function is perfectly acceptable.

---

With respect to the edit, *no* you cannot modify the previous interface. That would violate the Single Responsibility Principle, the Open/Closed Principle, and besides that, it would have nothing to do with the Decorator Pattern. If you edit the original interface, a Decorator is useless.

Comment: I've just edited my question if you want to take a look. I'll look at the GoF book, thanks !

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had been taught last year and it somehow always felt off (Still took me a year to actually check online, but at least i did it ! :) ). Thanks for the great clarification.