# Can The Decorator Pattern Add Properties Or Does It Only Update Function Implementations?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

Why I'm asking this question:

I have an object that might look like this (using JSON for simplicity):

```
{
   "Value1": 1,
   "Value2": 2
}
```

Now in the component that uses this object (or collection of said objects), I want to implement some business logic. Specifically, lets say I want to do something to a given object if Value2 ever drops below say 0. I can handle this by just adding a function that does something like:

```
if(object.Value2 < 0)
{
   //do something
}
```

But let's say I want to track whether or not this event ever happened for the duration of some time. Since I'm keeping track of multiple objects of this type, I could update my object to include a bool property, and toggle it whenever I needed:

```
{
   "Value1": 1,
   "Value2": 2,
   "EventHappened": True
}
```

I could then modify my function to update the boolean, then set and reset as needed. What if I want to use the same object, and I now need to check against Value1's value too? I can continually add properties and checks, but it seems kind of messy to continually have to update the component and base class this way. When looking into design patterns, the Decorator pattern - on paper - sounds like it would solve this problem. I would still need to modify my calling component, but I could simply dynamically add traits (such as "EventHappened" above). Is this a correct understanding of the pattern? Because in reading various examples and explanations about the Decorator pattern, most or all include an analogy of say adding "properties" or traits to the base object. However, when I actually look at the code, the pattern is really adding additional functionality to methods defined by an Interface. It's not actually dynamically adding properties to an object. It's just confusing because the most common example is a dynamic shape creation, with color as a property. And the examples are you can get a Circle, Square, RedCircle, GreenSquare, etc... Here's one:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorator-design-pattern-in-java-with-example/

But, each example simply modifies a method such as Draw() - which in the example is just writing to console and adding like "Red" to the output. How am I supposed to use the decorator pattern, and is there a pattern that might work for what I'm describing?

Comment: "I could simply dynamically add traits" Can you please explain what "dynamically" means in this context, exactly. Are you saying that you, the programmer, can add more properties as you write the code (which is always true), or are you saying that the program can add more traits at runtime?

Comment: Usually the decorator pattern is meant to modify the _behavior_ rather than the _shape/contract_ of an object. I would think hard about your _reasons for change_ and whether it really makes sense to have `EventHappened` properties on the same object as `Value1`, etc. Maybe you'd be better off with a separate data structure to track which events have been applied to which objects. It's hard to say without understanding your underlying problem better.

Comment: Yes, you can use the Decorator pattern to add both state and behavior to an object. I've quoted from the GoF in a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69426116/1371329). However, if this object is in code that you own and have the ability to edit, that is probably going to be simpler than maintaining a new decorator for every new requirement.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Let's say my object is a character for a game. I'd like for my character to have it's base traits (value1 and value2). But if something happens it also gets the exhausted property. I don't always want to track exhausted, I only want it applied and tracked if the event that causes exhaustion happens.

Comment: "I don't always want to track exhausted..." maybe elaborate on this? Are you concerned that having a boolean hanging around on the character will use up too much memory when most characters aren't exhausted most of the time? Are there only certain types of characters that can be exhausted? Would you rather hide the exhausted concept from most of your code because most of your game code shouldn't care whether the character is exhausted? Is exhaustion one of many possible character attributes? How do you expect other code to check whether a character is exhausted?

Comment: I think my biggest concern is that I'll have this largest superset of properties that grows anytime a requirement get added, or that objects that might inherit from the base class may or may not need some of those properties. I'm really just trying to ensure flexibility without code bloat.

Comment: IMHO, a better example is of a normal GUI `Panel` and a `ScrollPanel`. With that, you can see that there are properties and behavior added "dynamically." To the GUI framework, it's a drawable panel; it doesn't need to know the specifics as long as there's a `Draw` method it can call.